# Observers don't get called if wrapped within <adminhtml>, but get called without <adminhtml>

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer

I run into this odd situation where the observer doesn't get called if I wrapped it under adminhtml. For example the following observer is called when I saved a product.

```
 <events>
    <catalog_product_save_after>
        <observers>
            <testname_testmodule>
                <class>testname_testmodule/observer</class>
                <method>logUpdate</method>
                <type>singleton</type>
            </testname_testmodule>
        </observers>
    </catalog_product_save_after>
</events>
```

However, if I wrapped event within  like below, then it doesn't work.

```
<adminhtml>
    <events>
        <catalog_product_save_after>
            <observers>
                <testname_testmodule>
                    <class>testname_testmodule/observer</class>
                    <method>logUpdate</method>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                </testname_testmodule>
            </observers>
        </catalog_product_save_after>
    </events>
</adminhtml>
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: This should definitly work ... maybe there is a typo?

Comment: I considered that too, but the observer method `logUpdate` got called when the events is put outside <adminhtml>, though.

Comment: Can you post your (not working) config.xm?

Comment: Here you go https://gist.github.com/frostshoxx/e3104e1c4465843326219112388c507b

It doesn't work unless I take out <adminhtml> and </adminhtml> tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your Gist code this seems to be wrong nested...

```
<global>
     <adminhtml>
```

It should be ...

```
<global>
    ...
</global>
<frontend>
    ...
</frontend>
<adminhtml>
    ...
</adminhtml>
```

Answer (score 1):

@sv3n just helped me rubberduck debugging the issue.

Turned out `<adminhtml>...</adminhtml>` is supposed to be outside `<global>..</global>`

Comment: Maybe you'll still accept my answer ;) GN8 :)